React Native Mapbox follow user location and direction
I am using mapbox in react native and Im trying to make the app follow the user location along the path with the direction facing the path. I could only find documentation regarding the bearing but when I add it to the GET endpoint it doesnt seem to take any effect.
SO requests me to add more info,ignore the following text:
I am using mapbox in react native and Im trying to make the app follow the user location along the path with the direction facing the path. I could only find documentation regarding the bearing but when I add it to the GET endpoint it doesnt seem to take any effect.
I am using mapbox in react native and Im trying to make the app follow the user location along the path with the direction facing the path. I could only find documentation regarding the bearing but when I add it to the GET endpoint it doesnt seem to take any effect.

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import MapboxGL from '@rnmapbox/maps';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import tw from 'twrnc';
import useUserGeoLocation from '../../hooks/useUserGeoLocation';
import {SvgXml} from 'react-native-svg';
import locationSVG from '../../assets/icons/location';
import InstructionsModal from '../RouteInstructions';
import haversine from 'haversine';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import SDK from '@truckwisetech/truckwise-client-api';
import {ILocations} from '../../types/job';

let instructions: string[] = [];
const tokenmapbox =
  'myToken';
MapboxGL.setAccessToken(tokenmapbox);

MapboxGL.setTelemetryEnabled(false);

interface Props {
  coordinates: [number, number];
  jobId: string;
  location: ILocations;
}

const calculateDistance = (coords1: number[], coords2: number[]) => {
  let start = {
    longitude: coords1[0],
    latitude: coords1[1],
  };

  let end = {
    longitude: coords2[0],
    latitude: coords2[1],
  };
  const distance = haversine(start, end, {unit: 'meter'});
  return distance;
};

const TruckMapBox: React.FC<Props> = ({coordinates, jobId, location}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const {userCoordinates} = useUserGeoLocation();
  let userLatitude = userCoordinates.latlng.latitude;
  let userLongitude = userCoordinates.latlng.longitude;
  const [routeDirections, setrouteDirections] = useState(null);
  const [radius, setRadius] = useState(100);
  const [displayDistance, setDisplayDistance] = useState<number>(100);
  const [updateCount, setUpdateCount] = useState(0);

  const makeRouterFeature = (coordinates: [number, number]): any => {
    let routerFeature = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: 'LineString',
            coordinates,
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    return routerFeature;
  };

  async function createRouterLine(coords: [number, number]): Promise<void> {
    const endLatitude = coords[1];
    const endLongitude = coords[0];
    const geometries = 'geojson';
    const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving-traffic/${userLongitude},${userLatitude};${endLongitude}, ${endLatitude}?alternatives=false&annotations=distance%2Cmaxspeed%2Cduration%2Cspeed&geometries=${geometries}&language=en&overview=full&steps=true&max_height=4&max_width=3&max_weight=4&alley_bias=-1&voice_instructions=true&access_token=${tokenmapbox}`;

    let response = await fetch(url);
    let json = await response.json();
    const steps = json.routes[0].legs[0].steps;
    for (const step of steps) {
      instructions.push(step.maneuver.instruction);
    }
    let coordinates: [number, number] =
      json['routes'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'];
    if (coordinates.length) {
      const routerFeature = makeRouterFeature([...coordinates]);
      setrouteDirections(routerFeature);
    }
  }

  const updateLocationToChecked = async () => {
    const res = await SDK.JobModule.checkinJob(jobId, {
      locationId: location.id,
      latitude: userLatitude,
      longitude: userLongitude,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    });
    console.log('UPDATE CHECK RESULT =>', res);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    userLatitude = userCoordinates.latlng.latitude;
    userLongitude = userCoordinates.latlng.longitude;
  }, [userCoordinates.latlng.latitude, userCoordinates.latlng.longitude]);
  return (
    <>
      <View style={tw`flex-1 justify-center items-center`}>
        <View style={tw`flex-1 relative w-full`}>
          <Text style={tw`text-green-500 text-5xl`}>
            {displayDistance.toFixed(2)}
          </Text>
          <Text style={tw`text-green-500 text-5xl`}>{updateCount}</Text>
          {instructions.length > 0 && (
            <View style={tw`absolute top-0 left-0 z-10`}>
              <InstructionsModal instructions={instructions} />
            </View>
          )}

          <MapboxGL.MapView
            style={tw`flex-1`}
            zoomEnabled={true}
            styleURL="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12"
            rotateEnabled={true}
            onDidFinishLoadingMap={async () => {
              await createRouterLine(coordinates);
            }}>
            <MapboxGL.Camera
              zoomLevel={15}
              followUserLocation
              centerCoordinate={[
                userCoordinates.latlng.longitude,
                userCoordinates.latlng.latitude,
              ]}
              pitch={40}
              animationMode={'flyTo'}
              animationDuration={2000}
            />

            <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation id="marker" coordinate={coordinates}>
              <SvgXml xml={locationSVG} height={32} width={24} />
            </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>

            {routeDirections && (
              <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id="line1" shape={routeDirections}>
                <MapboxGL.LineLayer
                  id="routerLine01"
                  style={{
                    lineColor: '#033768',
                    lineWidth: 4,
                  }}></MapboxGL.LineLayer>
              </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
            )}

            <MapboxGL.UserLocation
              animated={true}
              requestsAlwaysUse={true}
              androidRenderMode="gps"
              visible={true}
              showsUserHeadingIndicator={true}
              onUpdate={async currentLocation => {
                const userCoords = [
                  currentLocation.coords.longitude,
                  currentLocation.coords.latitude,
                ];
                const distance = calculateDistance(userCoords, coordinates);
                setUpdateCount(prev => prev + 1);
                setDisplayDistance(distance);

                if (distance <= radius) {
                  updateLocationToChecked();
                  navigation.navigate('UploadTicketsView', {
                    jobId,
                  });
                }
              }}
            />
          </MapboxGL.MapView>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default TruckMapBox;


